# IE8/9 closes right after opening

Tags: internet-explorer

I have been having huge trouble trying to solve this issue and I need your help!

Issue:
When I open IE8 (32 bit), IE window comes up then closes within half a second.
Sometimes, it opens and stays up but in (Not responding) state for a minute, then closes.

I have dug around the internet to try the following:

- Reset IE setting to default via Internet Settings
- Run IE in no-addon mode
- Uninstall/reinstall IE8
- Run Spybot to clean malwares
- Install IE9, which ended up having same problem as IE8

and the problem still persists.

I am able to run Chrome, Firefox, IE8/9 (64 bit) with no problem.

Is there any other thing that I could try?

Answer (score 1):

Just as I posted the question, I browsed some more for the answer.

One I came across is:
http://cnedelcu.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/top-3-fixes-for-internet-explorer-wont.html

Method 1 and 2 I've already tried but method 3, which re-registers all the necessary files for IE, worked!

Thank goodness.. I think that is the only page which contained the answer I needed, seriously!